# AWS STS Assume Role: Get session token

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-sts

I am trying to get a session token for the given IAM in postman but not able to receive a token.

If I use boto3.client('sts'), I am able to get the token.

Use Case: I am trying to Invoke VPC Rest Endpoint from EC2 instance where ServiceNow mid-server instance is running. Since we have ServiceNow mid-server agent running on EC2 instance, I want to use IAM Role attached to EC2 to authenticate other VPC endpoints that are deployed in the same AWS account.

I have permission policy attached to IAM Role to allow Assume Role policy. If there any other approach, please suggest.

here HTML HTML response in postman. Postman redirecting to IAM Docs

[image]

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::**************:role/ServiceNow-midserver-Role',
    RoleSessionName='Session1',
    DurationSeconds=3600
    )
print(response)
```

anything wrong with postman request body or endpoint.
Authentication on postman is none.

[image]

Comment: How are you hoping to assume an IAM role without supplying credentials? Also, you didn't indicate what error response you received.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for you reply. I not getting error but empty response. Expected response should be access_key, secrete_key, and session token. The reason, I am using IAM to avoid key rotation.

Comment: You’re getting a 200 OK response? Or an HTTP error code?

Comment: @jarmod yes, I am getting 200 OK but in response, body has HTML content which does not have credentials

Comment: Is the response HTML or XML? It should be the latter, and will include the response.

Comment: @jarmod Its HTML response contains help link and documentation links for IAM. Its huge so I can't paste it here.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve issued a GET request to the sts endpoint and it’s redirected you the IAM home page. Check how you’re calling the API.

Comment: @jarmod I tried both GET & Post still the same response. I am sure something is wrong with the request body and endpoint as well.

Comment: You should review the [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)]. I’m not sure you can supply parameters as a JSON body - it might be supported, but I don’t immediately see it in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

To call AssumeRole from Postman (or curl etc.) as opposed to using a supported AWS SDK, you should follow the [AssumeRole API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html). You will also need to authenticate using AWS credentials.

Specifically, the request is an HTTP GET and parameters are passed as query strings, for example:

```
GET https://sts.amazonaws.com/
?Version=2011-06-15
&Action=AssumeRole
&RoleSessionName=stackoverflow-64706420
&RoleArn=arn:aws:iam::123456781234:role/myrole
&DurationSeconds=3600
```

Here's what this looks like in Postman:

[image]

And you will need to add AWS credentials so that your API request is signed correctly, for example:

[image]

Click 'Send' and the response will look something like this:

```
<AssumeRoleResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <AssumeRoleResult>
    <AssumedRoleUser>
      <Arn>arn:aws:sts::123456781234:assumed-role/123456781234/stackoverflow-64706420</Arn>
      <AssumedRoleId>ARO123EXAMPLE123:stackoverflow-64706420</AssumedRoleId>
    </AssumedRoleUser>
    <Credentials>
      <AccessKeyId>ASIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE</AccessKeyId>
      <SecretAccessKey>wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYzEXAMPLEKEY</SecretAccessKey>
      <SessionToken>
       AQoDYXdzEPT//////////wEXAMPLEtc764bNrC9SAPBSM22wDOk4x4HIZ8j4FZTwdQW
       LWsKWHGBuFqwAeMicRXmxfpSPfIeoIYRqTflfKD8YUuwthAx7mSEI/qkPpKPi/kMcGd
       QrmGdeehM4IC1NtBmUpp2wUE8phUZampKsburEDy0KPkyQDYwT7WZ0wq5VSXDvp75YU
       9HFvlRd8Tx6q6fE8YQcHNVXAkiY9q6d+xo0rKwT38xVqr7ZD0u0iPPkUL64lIZbqBAz
       +scqKmlzm8FDrypNC9Yjc8fPOLn9FX9KSYvKTr4rvx3iSIlTJabIQwj2ICCR/oLxBA==
      </SessionToken>
      <Expiration>2020-12-09T13:34:41Z</Expiration>
    </Credentials>
    <PackedPolicySize>6</PackedPolicySize>
  </AssumeRoleResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>c6104cbe-af31-11e0-8154-cbc7ccf896c7</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</AssumeRoleResponse>
```

Comment: thanks this worked. Any idea why GetSessionToken would not work (assuming it was added as a permission in the user ARN)?

Comment: @MitaleeRao what response do you get?

Comment: Actually I'm getting the tokens, but they don't work in another call I make to the SPAPIs. I guess they have disabled some config somewhere. AssumRole works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use credentials for an IAM user or an IAM role to call AssumeRole. boto3 must be getting credentials from the standard locations it look for (like ~/.aws/config) [ref:https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html]. May be you could try providing the AWS creds in Authorization tab in Postman selecting type as AWS Signature and then call assumeRole.

Comment: @JaueshCP I am trying to use assume role based on this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html